# multiple file upload error message in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

i am getting errors while uploading my files successfully. 
html input file is like

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" >
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" >
```

my controller function contain

```
$files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {           
                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                $this->upload->do_upload();
            }

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[0]')&&!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[1]'))
            { 
                $data['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); 
                $this->parser->parse('view_fileUploading',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $data['message'] = "Success"; 
                $this->parser->parse('view_fileUploading',$data);
            }
```

and

```
private function set_upload_options()
    {   
        $id = uniqid();
        $new_image_name = 'image_' . $id . '.png';
        //upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '0';
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
        $config['file_name'] = $new_image_name;


        return $config;
    }
```

in my images folder i am getting all my uploading images successfully but i am getting errors too which is like "You did not select a file to upload" [image]

i guess my

> if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[0]')&&!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/porh7.png)'))

isn't working properly

how can i get the successful message correctly ??

Answer (score 1):

You are opt to re-upload file at :

`if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[0]')&&!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile[1]'))`

However, understand that your file is already upload by `do_upload()`

`$this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                $this->upload->do_upload();`

Then, Your Actual solution should be:

```
$uploadStatus=array();
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['userfile']['size'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $uploadStatus[]=$this->upload->do_upload();
    }
    if (in_array('0',$uploadStatus)) {

        $data['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->parser->parse('view_fileUploading', $data);

    } else {
        $data['message'] = "Success";
        $this->parser->parse('view_fileUploading', $data);
    }
```